# XML serialization array issue in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml structure that i am trying to convert to C#, I appreciate the assistance:

```
<AnimalTypeList>
   <Type>Tiger</Type>
   <Type>Rabbit</Type>
<AnimalTypeList>
```

So far i have the following C# defined in my sample app. I am having difficulty correctly satisfying the above structure:

```
public class TestApp
{
  [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Type")]
  public AnimalTypeListType[] AnimalTypeList {get; set;}
}
```

Here is the other class

```
public class AnimalTypeListType
{
   [XmlElement]
   public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

Here is my schema:

```
 <xs:element name="AnimalTypeList" type="AnimalTypeListType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="AnimalTypeListType">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Type" maxOccurs="unbounded"  minOccurs="0"/>
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need one class

```
string xml = @"<AnimalTypeList>
                    <Type>Tiger</Type>
                    <Type>Rabbit</Type>
                </AnimalTypeList>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AnimalList));
var result = (AnimalList)serializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));


[XmlRoot("AnimalTypeList")]
public class AnimalList
{
    [XmlElement("Type")]
    public string[] Animals;
}
```